# Find the lowest value in for loop: How to initialize the comparison variable?

Tags: for-loop, foreach, compare

I need to find objects, which pass a certain test, and among all the objects that passed the first test, the one with the lowest value in another test. Say, I have to find the Swedish female with the lowest score in Tetris, from a sample group of people (assuming everyone has played Tetris(of course they have)).

I'm obviously doing a for loop, and do the tests, comparing the Tetris scores to the lowest score so far. But what should be the score to compare the first one to?

Normally I could also just take the first one and compare everything to that one afterwards, but they have to pass the first test too. I could also take an arbitrarily big number, but that's just wrong.

I could also make two loops and just gather all Swedish females on the first round, and then the scores on the second, but is there a shorter and more simple way?

Mock-up in C#:

```
bool AreYouSwedishFemale(Human patient)
{
    if(patient.isFemale && patient.isSwedish) {return true;}
    else {return false;}
}

int PlayTetris(Human patient)
{
    return someInt;
}

void myMainLoop()
{
    Human[] testSubjects = {humanA, humanB, humanC};
    Human dreamGirl;
    int lowestScoreSoFar; //What should this be?

    //Loop through testSubjects
    foreach(Human testSubject in testSubjects)
    {
        //Check if it's a Swedish Female
        if(AreYouSwedishFemale(testSubject))
        {
            //If so, compare her score to the lowest score so far
            if(PlayTetris(testSubject) < lowestScoreSoFar) //Error, uninitialized variable
            {
                //If the lowest, save the object to a variable
                dreamGirl = testSubject;
                //And save the score, to compare the remaining scores to it
                lowestScoreSoFar = PlayTetris(testSubject);
            }
        }
    }

    //In the end we have the result
    dreamGirl.marry();
}
```

Yea, I'm not really looking for girls to beat in Tetris, I'm coding in Unity, but tried to keep this independent of the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do a initialized check for "lowest score so far" before PlayTetris() check. Assuming that the lowest score is 0, you can initialize the lowest score to -1. Then edit your loop as such

```
//Loop through testSubjects
foreach(Human testSubject in testSubjects)
{
    //Check if it's a Swedish Female
    if(AreYouSwedishFemale(testSubject))
    {

        if( lowestScoreSoFar < 0 || PlayTetris(testSubject) < lowestScoreSoFar) 
        {
            //If the lowest, save the object to a variable
            dreamGirl = testSubject;
            //And save the score, to compare the remaining scores to it
            lowestScoreSoFar = PlayTetris(testSubject);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically if your "lowest score so far" hasn't been set, then the first swedish female you find will set it.

If for some reason the score is arbitrary, instead of doing -1 you could also just have a "lowestWasSet" bool that trips when the first girl is found.

Even better, you could also just do **(dreamGirl == null)** instead of **(lowestScoreSoFar < 0)** because your dream girl is null until you find the first Swedish female. C# short circuits its OR checks, so the first condition to pass will immediately jump into the block. So **dreamGirl == null** will pass as true and **PlayTetris() < lowestScoreSoFar** won't throw an uninitialized error.